# Cannot install phpmyadmin on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: server, apache2, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have installed ubuntu along side with window 10 (dual boot). I have set up apache2 server, mysql and install PHP 7, and then I want to install phpmyadmin I cannot install it. I have try many time, but still have the same problem.
And here is the error that I get:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 but it is not going to be installed or
                       libapache2-mod-php5filter but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-cgi but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php5-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-mysqli but it is not installable or
                       php5-mysqlnd but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php5-mcrypt but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php5-json but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php-gettext but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: php5-gd but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It says I have broken packages, and I really don't know how to fix this. Please help!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What it's telling you, is that the version of  phpmadmin on the repo depends on php5* packages. Since you installed php7, maybe that's the reason they won't be installed. You can install it manually downloading version 4.5.4.1 (compatible with php7) from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/. From what i remember is just uncompress it on a folder under the webroot, usually `/var/www/html/` for apache2.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). It will install all of them. It is also available for ubuntu.

Download .run file and install it like this

```
chmod 755 xampp-linux-*-installer.run
sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run
```

After this, you can run this like this.

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

And to stop

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

This will run its command line tool. It also has its graphical tool. It can be run like this.

```
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./manager-linux.run (or manager-linux-x64.run)
```

Comment: Thanx. I have updated it with necessery steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install php7 and then install phpmyadmin, this works for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-common php7.0-cli php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl php7.0-sqlite3 php7.0-json php7.0-tidy php7.0-mysql
sudo apt-get install -y phpmyadmin
```