# Problem installing phpmyadmin after upgrading to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, phpmyadmin

I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and my phpmyadmin installation just vanished (I guess I did something wrong!). I've tried to reinstall it, but got this:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
phpmyadmin : Depends: php but it is not installable
             Depends: php-cli but it is not installable
             Depends: php-mysql but it is not installable
             Depends: php-json but it is not installable
             Depends: php-mbstring but it is not installable
             Depends: php-xml but it is not installable
             Recommends: php-gd but it is not installable
             Recommends: php-bz2 but it is not installable
             Recommends: php-zip but it is not installable
             Recommends: php-tcpdf but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can install php7(`apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y` and `apt-get update
&& apt-get install -y php7.0-common php7.0-cli php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl php7.0-sqlite3 php7.0-json php7.0-tidy php7.0-mysql`), this solved my problem. The details has already been posted in another anwser, so I will just link it here: https://askubuntu.com/a/917628/621561